# Html.BeginForm() does not submit if nothing is selected in a Html.Dropdownlist() helper with optional label

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-submit, html.dropdownlistfor, html.beginform

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Boxing", "Company",FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    <div class="box">
        <div>
            <div class="left">
                <div class="topLabel">
                    Id No:</div>
                <div class="input_text_65">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id)
                </div>
                <div class="botLabel">
                    percentt:
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" style="width: 50px" name="percent" />%
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lastDetailField">
                <div class="topLabel">
                    D/C:
                </div>
                <div class="select_110">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.cType, new SelectList((IEnumerable<Model.cType>)ViewData[ViewDataKeys.cTypes]), "----")
                </div>
                <div class="margin_top_45">
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

If I didn't select any option in the dropdownlist (leaving the optionlabel "----" selected) and I press the submit button, the form will not be posted and the focus will be move to the dropdownlist

if I remove the optional Label, like this:

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.cType, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData[ViewDataKeys.cTypes]))

then it will work just fine. I'm thinking if I will put an optional label, does that mean I am required to choose an item? I want the form to be submitted even if I leave the dropdownlist with the optionallabel selected.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a required attribute in your model/viewmoden on cType? I think the clientside validation is kicking in, but because you didn't set a validation helper, you're not seeing the message. The form won't submit though if you select the optional label.

Comment: thanks. now that explains it. The problem now is that I checked my models,mappings and db that it is a nullable field. even on my model, its just a plain property declaration and no attributes. any ideas on how prevent the auto required validation?

Comment: Is the property in the model nullable? MVC creates automatic validation for non-nullable fields like int, datetime etc. You should set int? or datetime? in those cases.